# Div width not changing with responsive css

Tags: html, css

I want the div width to be 100vw when screen size is below 480px.  I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```css
#testdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #testdiv {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #0000ff
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="testdiv">
    test
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I change screen size, nothing happens.

Comment: Works fine for me - Something else in your page might be be causing the issue.

Comment: I've added your code to a snippet, and as you can see it works perfectly. If its not working in your project, then something else is causing the problem.

Comment: Add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the head tag.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had to add the following html tag to the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Also note - that any 'block' level element (display: block) - will be 100% width of its parent - by default. : )